# How do I append values from Firestore to a local array, without an empty array error?

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save some form values to Firestore, then display those values as IBOutlet variables in a table view cell.

So far, the values are successfully saved to Firestore and I have a snapshot listener with a model to convert those Firestore values to a local array. However, the values cannot be appended to the array and I keep getting the "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array" error.

The strange thing is this same set of code (with variable name changes) was used for another feature and it worked perfectly.

I did my print() checks and confirmed the array is empty. The IBOutlets are also properly connected and I did my best to make sure the Firestore async call happens before the table view cell populates the values.

And I'm still stuck with the "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array" fatal error. I must be missing something very obvious here.

```
// I declared the meds array storing "Med" as a model created to convert Firestore form values to a local array

var meds = [Med]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if meds.count > 0 {
            print("Nice!")
        } else {
            print("Empty array")
        }

        // Creates empty view when no meds are added
        tableView.backgroundView = emptyView
        tableView.backgroundView?.isHidden = true

        // Customize table view styles
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.tableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Listens to changes in meds data
        medListener = ref.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error listening for channel updates: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
                return
            }

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
                self.handleDocumentChange(change)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
// Helper methods to update changes in table view cell with Firestore, and vice versa

func addMedToTable(_ med: Med) {
        guard !meds.contains(med) else {
            return
        }

        // Add new med to meds array
        meds.append(med)
        meds.sort()

        guard let index = meds.firstIndex(of: med) else {
            return
        }
        print(index)

        // Adds new med into table view
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

    func updateMedInTable(_ med: Med) {
        guard let index = meds.firstIndex(of: med) else {
            return
        }

        meds[index] = med
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

    func removeMedFromTable(_ med: Med) {
        guard let index = meds.firstIndex(of: med) else {
            return
        }

        meds[index] = med
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }

    func handleDocumentChange(_ change: DocumentChange) {
        guard let med = Med(document: change.document) else {
            return
        }

        switch change.type {
        case .added:
            addMedToTable(med)

        case .modified:
            updateMedInTable(med)

        case .removed:
            removeMedFromTable(med)

        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You said "did my best to make sure the Firestore async call happens before the table view cell populates the values." Need to make sure, although I don't have that context in your code sample. Where is the code breaking? If you have an async network call, you need to confirm completion prior to processing any data that is supposed to be returned.

Comment: Did find your solution?